# Sharepoint 2013 DFS

Tags: 2013, file

Im running a Sharepoint 2013 server and got a fileserver with different DFS shares.

Are there any way for me to map one of the DFS shares into a sharepoint site?

Comment: Could you add more info about what you mean by mapping the share to SharePoint site?

Comment: I got a Sharepoint intranet site. One of our departments got a DFS share named ex. \\domain\dfs\economics.

Can I get those files in that share to be visible in the sharepoint site?

Comment: What you could do is to index them so you can search for documents in your fileshare in SharePoint and open them from there, might be something?

Comment: Good idea :) But, how do I do that?

Comment: Do you know the basics of sharepoint search like creating content sources etc? https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219577.aspx

Comment: Yes ofcourse. The indexing part is no problem. I thought you meant, indexing the whole share so its visible. I got your point